# losing data when using dynamic_cast to derive object

Tags: c++

when I push `fifoGroundEvtEntry` data inside `list_fifoGroundEvt` from another thread using `sender::GetInstance()->getDataCollector()->pushGroundEventFifo(entry);` and when I debug puting one breakpoint inside `pushGroundEventFifo` function I can see the correct value of `grdEvt.x` and `grdEvt.y` inside `list_fifoGroundEvt`.

then when I call `test` method inside `transmit` methode and I pute breakpoint inside test. I see wrong values inside `list_fifoGroundEvt`-> grdEvt.y = 0x00F12751 for entry.y = 2 !

PS: `transmit()` is a thread and I start it using `sender::GetInstance()->start()` (I didn't put all functions I put only those who have a link with the problem )

the thread is starting after pushing entries inside `list_fifoGroundEvt`

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <list>

    struct fifoEvtEntry {
        virtual ~fifoEvtEntry() {}
        int x;
    };


    struct fifoGroundEvtEntry : fifoEvtEntry
    {
        int y;
    };

    class collector {
    public:
        void pushGroundEventFifo(fifoEvtEntry& entry) {
            if (fifoGroundEvtEntry* grdEvt = dynamic_cast<fifoGroundEvtEntry*>(&entry))
            {
                list_fifoGroundEvt.push_back(grdEvt);
            }
        }

        void test() {
            if (fifoGroundEvtEntry* grdEvt = dynamic_cast<fifoGroundEvtEntry*>(list_fifoGroundEvt.front()))
            {
                std::cout << grdEvt ->y << std::endl;
            }
            list_fifoGroundEvt.pop_front();

        }

    private:
            std::list<fifoEvtEntry*> list_fifoGroundEvt;
    };

    class sender {
    public:
        sender(collector* data):_data(data) {};
        ~sender() {};
        static void setInstance(collector* data) {
            _instance = new sender(data);
        }
        static sender* GetInstance() {
            return _instance;
        }
        void transmit() {
            // this is a thread function
            // ..
            _data->test();
        }
        collector* getDataCollector(){
             return _data;
        }

        static sender* _instance;

 private:
        collector* _data;
    };

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please post a [mcve]. `int x` is a syntax error, ie the code you posted does not produce wrong results, it does not compile

Comment: Are you accessing any of the mentioned resources from different threads simultaneously? I see no synchronization objects whatsoever ...

Comment: @TedLyngmo I didn't mentionne that but yes I use critical sections to synchronise access.

Comment: If you run this code does it reproduce your problem? If not please show a [mre]

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem without using threads? If yes, then you should not show code that uses threads - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. If no, and you still have the problem in spite of your attempt to use critical sections, then show an example that includes critical sections as you are using them - in case that's the cause of the problem.

Comment: What you see when you stop at a breakpoint may or may not be relevant. Please make a program that produces some output, then show the output produced vs the output you expect. I conservatively modified your program such that it produces output [and I cannot reproduce your problem](https://godbolt.org/z/5x8en7aMM), the output is as expected.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I second this. I re-created what you've shown and I'm getting the output I would have expected.